# How to get only matching part of a string?

Tags: bash

I know how to use the utility `sed` in `bash`, and `grep` is also good. But for the output, they always output a line containing the pattern.

Is there a way in `bash` to cut out a particular string containing the pattern I want (using `regexp`)?

Comment: `grep -o` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you have `--help` flag, `grep --help`:

> **-o**, --only-matching       show *only* the part of a line matching PATTERN

Now you can

```
$ echo 'hello world' | grep -o hello
hello
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo "hello world" | sed 's/.*\(hello\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Is there any way to use `sed` to do that? I am just curious, not for a particular goal.

Comment: Is the `\1` affecting the result? I don't see any about this in the `sed` manual page.

Comment: @Chromium `\1` is the first group, which is the `hello`. It's a regex thing.

Comment: so what does the command `sed 's/.*\(hello\).*/\1/'` really means?

Comment: It doesn't mean to translate the `regexp` to group first, right?

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU grep` you can use `-o`:

> -o Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Example:

```
$ echo ab cd ef gh | grep a
ab cd ef gh
$ echo ab cd ef gh | grep -o a
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'hello world' | sed 's/\(hello\)\|./\1/g'
hello

$ echo 'hello world' | sed -r 's/(hello)|./\1/g'
hello
```